# Restarting loop Ubuntu 20.04.06 after update

Tags: boot, 20.04, gnome

On my laptop, there is an issue with Ubuntu restarting the loop after the update, in recovery mode, it's working. I tried many methods like reinstalling drivers, reconfiguring gdm3, select Noveau driver but still on loop restart.